# Select rows between X number and Y number

Tags: mysql, sql, select

so let's say I have `5000` rows, I want to select the rows from `2000 to 3000` only, how to do that via a `SQL query`?

Comment: use between and clause.

Comment: you can do it simply by using LIMIT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select * from table limit 2000,1000
```

limit from,how-many

Comment: Works, thanks. Is there's a way to make it find the how-many by itself? I just insert the from and the to. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't understand, what do you want?

Comment: I put the FROM and TO in the query and it selects the rows between them. Not FROM and HOW MANY.

Comment: Never mind, yours worked. I can't rep up. Thanks!

Comment: You need PHP script or smart mysql client to do this. Or you can select rows with ID, for example, between two numbers, but it's not about your topic question. If your rows has ID column with increment number, try SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID BETWEEN 2000 AND 3000

Comment: Be wary that this is non-deterministic, without an `ORDER BY` clause this query could return a different set of records each time it is run.